# Entering and exiting variables' relation to the value of the objective function in the Simplex method

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, simplex-method

Consider a maximisation LP problem. In the Simplex method, one of the rules for choosing which non-basic variable enters the new basis is too look at which one of the non-basic variables will give the largest increase to the objective function, and then proceed. However, why can't it happen that all of the basic variables, one of which should exit, will all give a larger decrease to the objective function than the increase the entering variable will give, so that no matter which variable we will choose for exit, our objective function will decrease? What argument forbids that?

---

My conditions are in the form of $Ax=b$, where $b=(7,-5,3)^T$, $A=\begin{bmatrix}12&12&1&1&-1\\-8&-6&0&-1&0\\11&10&1&1&-2\end{bmatrix}$.

I introduce  artificial variables $a_1,a_2, a_3$ for each row. And try to minimise their sum. I proceed with the simplex algorithm, where square brackets indicate pivotal elements.

\begin{bmatrix}x_1&x_2&x_3&x_4&x_5&a_1&a_2&a_3\\12&12&1&1&-1&1&0&0&7\\-8&-6&0&-1&0&0&1&0&-5\\11&\boxed{10}&1&1&-2&0&0&1&3\\-15&-16&-2&-1&3&0&0&0&-5\end{bmatrix} (here I rewrote the last row in terms of the non-basic variables, as it is laid out here: http://www.maths.qmul.ac.uk/~ffischer/teaching/opt/notes/notes8.pdf )

\begin{bmatrix}-1.2&0&-0.2&-0.2&1.4&1&0&-1.2&3.4\\-1.4&0&0.6&-0.4&-1.2&0&1&0.6&-3.2\\1.1&1&\boxed{0.1}&0.1&-0.2&0&0&0.1&0.3\\2.6&0&-0.4&0.6&-0.2&0&0&1.6&-0.2\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0&0&\boxed{1}&1&0&-1&4\\-8&-6&0&-1&0&0&1&0&-5\\11&10&1&1&-2&0&0&1&3\\7&4&0&1&-1&0&0&2&1\end{bmatrix}

\begin{bmatrix}1&2&0&0&1&1&0&-1&4\\-8&-6&0&-1&0&0&1&0&-5\\13&14&1&1&0&2&0&-1&11\\8&6&0&1&0&1&0&1&5\end{bmatrix}

I stop since there are no negative coefficients left. However, it appears that the minimum of $a_1+a_2+a_3$ is 5, instead of 0. Must I have made a mistake somwhere? And the basis I ended up with is $(x_5,a_2,x_3)$. Shouldn't all a's be gone from the basis to proceed to phase 2?

Comment: At a maximization problem the entering variable has a negative coefficient at the objective function.  Then automatically the objective function increases due the rules of calculation of the updated value of the objective function,.

Comment: @callculus Say i have the function $z=x_1+1.5x_2+2x_3+3x_4+5x_5$. Basic variables at a current step of the SImplex method are $x_3,x_4,x_5$. With the feasible basic solution vector having 0 and 0 at $x_1$ and $x_2$. I must then by the rule choose $x_2$ to enter, since 1.5 is larger than 1. But then i will have to lose one basic variable that had an even larger coefficient. And the objective function must decrease? And could that amount be larger than the increase gained from $x_2$? I'm sure i don't understand something fundamental here..

Comment: @callculus .I have an exercise that doesnt need slack variables (already equalities) which would usually be dropped with no effect on the objective fucntion since they are absent from the expression for it

Comment: It is hard to comprehend your numerical example since you haven´t it posted in total. It would be better if you post the whole problem by editing your question. In general: If you have equalities as constraints the simplex algorithm requires *artificial variables* .

Comment: @callculus I have edited my post now and included the problem and my attempt at solving it (so far unsuccesful)